# Can you disable Gmail but still hold the address to prevent impersonation?

Tags: gmail

I want to disable my Gmail account and have all emails rejected.

But I do not want anyone else to register my old name and receive my emails or pretend to be me.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not retain the account, but set a filter to return a message whenever an e-mail is received to tell correspondents your new contact details?

Comment: @AFH I don't really want the account to be active.  What you describe almost works, but not quite.  For example, I have to remember to log in every few months.  Also, there are legal implications; e.g. if that is known to be my email address and someone sends an email there, there is expectation that I read the email, etc

Comment: @CaptainCodeman Where do you live? I've never heard of a legal implication like that. As you say you want to keep the mail for impersonation, assume someone else is using the mail in the future, then you wouldn't be expected to have read it, if you get what I'm trying to say. An idea would be to completely delete the account, then make a new one with the same mail and just leaving it be (and/or filtering/routing every message you get into a void, or returning a failure message, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just delete the account. The address will not become available for registration.

[Source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/56256):

> You won't be able to get a certain Gmail address if the username you requested is:
>
> […] The same as a username that someone used in the past and then deleted